# Regex To Mach Mergecodes with Double Hashtag

Tags: regex

I'm working with some RegEx to match all my merge codes in documents..

The mergecodes are like this.

```
##customer.name
##customer.eployee.address
```

etc

I have made this quite simple regex

```
\S*##\S*
```

that helps me to match allmost all cases since it take white space as "delimiter" and it works for the three below examples:

```
1
##customer.name ##customer.address

2
##customer.name ##customer.address

3
##customer.name     ##customer.address
```

But not in these:

```
1
##customer.name##customer.address 

2
##customer.name,##customer.address 

3
##customer.name--##customer.address
```

I know that I have to make it start over everytime it meets a new ## but all the things I have been trying doesn't seem to work .

Tried this after searching, but it doesn't do the trick :(

```
\S*##[^##\s]*
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: Try `##[^#\s]+\b` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/5HMHEr/2)). Or `##\w+(?:\.\w+)*` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/5HMHEr/1))

Comment: Ahh of course. Had overlooked the word boundary option. This actually does just the right thing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use either of the two approaches:

```
##[^#\s]+\b
##\w+(?:\.\w+)*
```

See [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/5HMHEr/2) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/5HMHEr/1).

**Details**

- `##` - matches `##` substring
- `[^#\s]+\b` - any 1+ chars other than `#` and whitespace, as many as possible, but should stop at the rightmost word boundary
- `\w+(?:\.\w+)*` - matches 1+ letters/digits/underscores and then any 0 or more sequences of `.` and 1+ letters/digits/underscores.

Answer (score 0):

```
##[\w.]+
```

This matches starting double hashes
then one or more alphanumeric characters or dots (.).

[demo here](https://regex101.com/r/vb5Dwa/1)

Comment: please escape the dot in the set

Comment: @Predicate we don't need to excape a dot. Its a literal. In a character class (square brackets) any character except ^, -, ] or \ is a literal